# How to setup player prefab for football game

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

I am Working on a football game project in unity.
This is a 2-player android game in which each team will have 5 players... i have setup all the game and now i got stuck in Networking.
I want to do networking using the **UNET not Photon**.

For this, I have read the unity documentation for networking at this link : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSetup.html

Its very easy and work fine because in their documentation there is one cube only for which they setup the player prefab.
**But, in my case there are 5 players for each team and 1 soccer ball and one football field. I have no idea whether i have to setup player prefab for all the team members(gameobjects) or there is any other solution to this because i dont want my game to be slowed down.**

PS: i am beginner in game development, any good solution or opinion will be really appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the worst thing you can do is connecting 5 players on the same device. it's going to make too much noise on the network and it's really hard to manage.

However ,the easiest way of doing it's by creating a manager (the player prefab) that going to spawn the 5 other "player" for the soccer ball, you can control it on the server-side.

Comment: But that's the same thing you told before @olivier